# Animating a sequence of Raphael Javascript Animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

Using JavaScript, I have created an array of objects. One of the object's properties is a Raphael shape.

Using `$.each(arr, function() {});`, I've drawn the shapes but I would like them to `fadeIn` in quick succession. So `arr[1].hexagon` would `fadeIn` then `arr[2]` and so on. I've been able to get them all the `fadeIn` in unison by just attaching `.animate()` to the object, but I can't figure out how to time the JavaScript.

I guess more generally, are there any tips for controlling sequence and time using Raphael or jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't use raphael or jquery, but is just a way of delaying iterations over an array in javascript:

```
var doSomethingWithValue = function(v) {
    // your call to animate the object, or do anything really.
    console.log(v);
}

var timer = function(a, n) {       
    var delay = 1000; // a second, probably change this to same duration as the fadeIn()
    doSomethingWithValue(a[n]); // do work
    n += 1;
    if (n == a.length) {
        // if we're at the end, return
        return;
    } else {
        // repeat after delay
        setTimeout(function() {timer(a, n)}, delay);
    }
}

var arr = [1,2,3];
// kick things off starting at first entry
timer(arr, 0);
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks oli. I'll look at this and see if it makes sense

Comment: I'm still not sure how you made that work, but it does work. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex glad it helped - if you think some elaboration is required, let me know and I can update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to solve this problem, but didn't want to depend on setTimeout (timers can behave oddly when the browser is minimized, and generally seems like it's not using Raphael correctly).

So, inspired by [trampolines](http://raganwald.com/2013/03/28/trampolines-in-javascript.html),  I made an animation queue.

The general strategy is to push anonymous functions into a queue, requiring that somewhere in the function, `animations.next` is either called directly or given to an animation to trigger.

```
animations = function() {
  var animationQueue = []
    , obj = {}

  obj.push = function(fn) {
    animationQueue.push(fn)
  }

  obj.next = function() {
    if (animationQueue.length !== 0) {
      animationQueue.shift().call()
    }
  }

  return obj
}()
```

Then you can do something like this a few times:

```
animations.push(function() {
  paper.circle(x, y, 2)
    .attr('fill', '#fff')
    .animate({r: radius}, animationSpeed, animations.next)
})
```

Finally, at the end of whatever it is you're doing, call `animations.next()` to start the chain.

Comment: I'm not sure even what the original question was, but it's always neat to see someone add an answer after a year and half. Time flies.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the callback provided by raphael Element.animate method.

```
window.onload = function () {
el.animate({theAnimation}, 1000, nextAnim);
}

function nextAnim(){ 
el2.animate({theAnimation2}, 1000);
}
```

The callback will call the specified function when the animation is finished. You can repeat this as many times as needed.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this code:

for(var i=0;i < numofObj;i++){

```
 Obj[i].animate({any animate you choose     },1000,function(){
 Obj[i+1].animate({any animate you choose},1000);
```

});

That will make the next obj animation only when the previous end...